# UNNotificationServiceExtension persistent connect

Tags: objective-c

TCP persistent connect in UNNotificationServiceExtension can not connect to server.

Ex:MQTTClient framework

Is the result of UNNotificationServiceExtension may keep alive no more than 30s? so UNNotificationServiceExtension cannot perform persistent connect

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Comment: MQTTClient used in UNNotificationServiceExtension